# Which tense to choose?

Tags: tense

Which is correct:

> "**I'm having** a good time here in Italy this week."

or:

> "**I have had** a good time here in Italy this week."

Comment: When are you saying this? During the week or after it?

Comment: Or *I have been having a good time here in Italy this week*, which is almost equivalent to your first example (in that they both imply the week isn't over yet). But my alternative at least allows for (but doesn't actually imply) the possibility that you're aware you might *not* enjoy the remaining time so much). As @user3169 implies, your second version strongly suggests that you've either left or are just about to leave Italy. Note that feasibly you *could* use your first version even if you actually *live* in Italy, and aren't planning to leave soon.

Comment: ...also note that feasibly you could come out with your first version even while you're travelling to Italy (referring to the good time you *will* have, as in *I'm going to London tomorrow*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having a good time here in Italy this week

This is correct to say if, when you say this, you are still having a good time in Italy and it's still the same week.

Because you are explicitly mentioning "this week", you are making fact that important, and therefore you could be implying that in some other previous week, you were not having a good time, or that there is a possibility you might not have a good time in future weeks.

> I have had a good time here in Italy this week.

This is implying that you are done with the "good time", though the week is not over.  This could be because it's the end of the week, you are next going to do other things that are not a "good time", or you are about to leave Italy.